# c++ tcp socket receive method review

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have working on a tcp client application which will send and waiting for response data from server.

My protocol is: client will send some data and it will wait for maximum 3 secs to get the corresponding ack from server. If it fails to receive the same within mentioned time period it will try twice more. Now using below code I'm checking whether the receiving is failing for 3 consicutive seconds.

I'm setting the socket in non blocking mode and then first checks for readibility mode by select(). Do I really need this select() call, as the client is not at all in listening mode, its making the communicating by following approach:

1. connect() to server
2. send() data
3. recv() data
4. goto point 2 if success

Now I have two questions with below code. Shall I use select() and am I doing it correctly by checking the timeout using GetTickCount()?

```
bool CTCPCommunication::ReceiveSocketData(char* pchBuff, int iBuffLen)
{
  bool bReturn = true;
  SetNonBlockingMode(true);

  //check whether the socket is ready to receive
  fd_set stRead;
  FD_ZERO(&stRead);
  FD_SET(m_hSocket, &stRead);
  int iRet = select(0, &stRead, NULL, NULL, &m_stTimeout);

  DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
  DWORD dwCurrentTime = 0;

  //if socket is not ready this line will be hit after 3 sec timeout and go to the end
  //if it is ready control will go inside the read loop and reads data until data ends or
  //socket error is getting triggered continuously for more than 3 secs.
  if ((iRet > 0) && (FD_ISSET(m_hSocket, &stRead)))
  {
    while ((iBuffLen-1) > 0)
    {
      int iRcvLen = recv(m_hSocket, pchBuff, iBuffLen-1, 0);
      dwCurrentTime = GetTickCount();

      if ((iRcvLen == SOCKET_ERROR) && ((dwCurrentTime - dwStartTime) >= SOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000))
      {
        bReturn = false;
        break;
      }

      pchBuff  += iRcvLen;
      iBuffLen -= iRcvLen;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    WRITELOG("Failed to socket call 'select' inside 'ReceiveSocketData' with error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    bReturn = false;
  }

  SetNonBlockingMode(false);
  return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: Your error handling is unacceptable in its entirety. Any system call must be followed by a test for -1 and a block that either calls `perror()` immediately *or* uses the result of `strerror()` immediately somehow, and then prevents execution from continuing as though the error hadn't happened. Try again.

Comment: I'm working on windows platform. Can you show some quick example what you said?

Comment: A quick example of `(if rc == -1) { perror("name of system call"); return;}`? Did you really need that?

Comment: Are you talking about select() method else portion where I'm printing some logs?

Comment: Anyone with any comments?